# What does “chiney” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

“And do ye carry your flock bed, and your quilt, and your crock, and your bit of **chiney**? or do ye go in bare bones, as I may say?” inquired Christopher Coney.
“I’ve sent on my luggage—though it isn’t much; for the voyage is long.” Donald’s eyes dropped into a remote gaze as he added: “But I said to myself, ‘Never a one of the prizes of life will I come by unless I undertake it!’ and I decided to go.”

Comment: *Chiney* is a dialect pronunciation of *china*.

Comment: He means "china" as in cups and plates, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Chiney is a dialect pronunciation of china.

– [StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131436/what-does-chiney-mean#comment264467_131436)